# Map values in a List based on custom Dictionary - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of numbers:

```
a = [4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,........................,4,3,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4]
```

I want to transform the values according to a custom dictionary, for example:

```
cust_dict ={4:'four',1:'one',2:'two',3:'three'}
```

To get the following:

```
a= [four,four,four,four,four.....,four, three,two,....]
```

The only code I have done is with a for loop:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
   a[i] = cust_dict[a[i]]
```

Is there a more efficient way (in pure python), thus avoiding for-loop ?
For a list of 35k items I took around 4ms with this code.

Comment: List Comprehension! `a = [cust_dict[i] for i in a]`

Comment: You can use list comprehension, but it won't give you significant boost.

Comment: Mapping! `a = list(map(lambda x: cust_dict[x], a))`

Comment: @ArvinKushwaha, `a = list(map(cust_dict.get, a))` would be much better.

Comment: try `a=list(map(cust_dict.get, a))` and see if it's any faster

Comment: @OlvinRoght dict.get is significantly slower than directly indexing. If you are certain that all the data is "safe" then your best bet is indexing. But yeah, if it isn't "safe", then dict.get is better.

Comment: @ArvinKushwaha, `lambda` will be much slower anyway.

Comment: 4ms isn't slow. If you have lists of (over) 35K, you may want to look at other options to store and use your data. Pandas Series type even has a nice `.map()` method, which should work very straightforwardly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List comprehension vs map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/list-comprehension-vs-map)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With 35K items, I would use a NumPy array, or in this context, a Pandas Series (this obviously ignores the "pure Python" mention in your question):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> a = [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
>>> cust_dict ={4:'four',1:'one',2:'two',3:'three'}
>>> s = pd.Series(a)
>>> s.map(cust_dict).tolist()
['four', 'four', 'four', 'four', 'four', 'four', 'three', 'three', 'three', 'three', 'three', 'three', 'three', 'three', 'three', 'two', 'two', 'two', 'four', 'four', 'four', 'one', 'one', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'two', 'three']
```

But you may not want to convert the series back to a list, depending on further needs and usage.

Answer (score 3):

Thank for the mapping, I was looking exactly for something like that.
In term of speed (on my list (35k entries)):

1. List Comprehension (@Arvin Kushwaha): `a = [cust_dict[i] for i in a]` --> 3 ms
2. Lambda Mapping(@Arvin Kushwaha) : `a = list(map(lambda x: cust_dict[x], a))` --> 5.54ms
3. Dict get Mapping(@Olvin Roght) : `a=list(map(cust_dict.get, a)` --> 2ms

PS: pandas mapping took 9ms (with transforming back the pd.series to a list)
Thank you all!

Comment: Depending on further needs, you may want to keep things as an array or series, instead of using lists again. Lists can be fast, but at some point, an array or series will outdo a Python list.

Comment: I agree, if I have additionnal processing behind, to let things in series or arrays.

Comment: @Pdeuxa, if you're really obsessed with execution time, you can replace you `cust_dict` with `cust_list = [None, 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four']` and use `list(map(cust_list.__getitem__, a))`, it should be slightly faster.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this:

```
a= [4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4]

cust_dict ={4:'four',1:'one',2:'two',3:'three'}

output = list(map(lambda x: cust_dict[x], a))

print(output)
# ['four', 'four', 'four', 'four', 'four', 'four', 'four', 'four', 'four', 'four', 'three', 'two', 'three', 'three', 'three', 'three', 'three', 'three', 'three', 'three', 'three', 'three', 'three', 'three', 'three', 'three', 'three', 'three', 'three', 'three', 'three', 'three', 'three', 'three', 'three', 'three', 'four']
```

Answer (score 0):

a[:] = map(lambda x:cust_dict[x], a)